# SQL , Transform "...str." to "strasse"

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I transform "Odenwaldstr." to "Odenwald Strasse".

In German one can write it this way or this way. For my project I need to put it in one way. Meaning all street names that ends with "...str." need to end with "... Strasse"

Comment: check http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-string.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use postgres in built replace method, as  REGEXP_REPLACE instead REPLACE method will be replace all part of the string

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name,'.(str?)$', 'Strasse');
```

instead of

```
 SELECT REPLACE(column_name , 'str', ' Strasse')
```

Check more about postgres string handling here
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

Comment: This is quite dangerous.  Unexpected things will happen if the street name contains "str".

Comment: @GordonLinoff That's true :-D

Answer (score 1):

You need to be very careful with this, lest you replace `str` in other parts of the word.  Assuming the `str` is at the end of the column, I would recommend a safer approach:

```
select (case when col like '%str.' then substr(col, length(col) - 4) || ' Strasse'
             when col like '%str' then substr(col, length(col) - 3) || ' Strasse'
             else col
        end) as ColWithStrasse
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion :-)  I updated my answer with REGEXP_REPLACE to replace the str to Strasee